# Ajax Submit Form Self Page - two buttons

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, submit

I want to make a simple form which posts value 1 and value two. So I made this simple form just to make tests:

```
<form method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
<button id="submit" type='submit' value="1" id="master_zoom" name="master_zoom">Zoom 1</button><br/><br/>
<button id="submit2" type='submit' value="2" id="master_zoom" name="master_zoom">Zoom 2</button>
</form><br/>
```

This form posts the values in the same page. Can you guys tell me how can I make a ajax form and post the same thing to the same page without reloading the page?

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context

Comment: Oh, sorry. Stupid mistake... But can you help me with AJAX?

Comment: You have to provide your failing attempt then someone could try to fix it

Comment: come on, just google it with some of the words.., form, ajax, jquery...

Comment: you can do that by javascript (jquery is better for me).. so as @reyaner said google it.. and please make a lil search before post your question

Comment: Guys I've been trying and googling more than 3 hours. I would ask you if knew how to do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using JQuery. Not sure if this helps answer your question, but here is a jsfiddle that should hopefully point you in the right direction.

http://jsfiddle.net/e5bq3x2z/

HTML

```
<button class="zoom" id="zoom1" type='submit' value="1" >Zoom 1</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<button class="zoom" id="zoom2" type='submit' value="2" >Zoom 2</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<input id="myinput" value="submitted value"></input>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#zoom1").click(function(){
     var myvalue = $("#zoom1").val();
      $("#myinput").val(myvalue);
  });

  $("#zoom2").click(function(){
     var myvalue = $("#zoom2").val();
      $("#myinput").val(myvalue);
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you so much! You are a good person!